# File Entries API: When is it completed?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm using the [File Entries API](https://wicg.github.io/entries-api/) to read files dragged and dropped onto a web page and eventually upload them. It requires all sorts of complex code to iterate the dropped files which looks like it could be asynchronous (but it's not clear). When I do nothing special, the code completes before all files have been seen. So there definitely needs to be some synchronisation in place.

Here's my current guess:

```
element.on("drop", function(event) {
    // API spec: https://wicg.github.io/entries-api/
    if (event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.items) {
        addFileEntries(event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.items);
    }
    else {
        files = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
        upload(files);
    }
});

function addFileEntries(entries) {
    let files = [];
    asyncWaitCount++;
    for (const item of entries) {
        // kind will be "file" for file/directory entries
        if (item.kind === "file") {
            const entry = item.webkitGetAsEntry();
            addDroppedFile(entry, files);
        }
    }
    asyncWaitCount--;
    if (!asyncWaitCount) upload(files);
}

function addDroppedFile(entry, files) {
    if (entry.isDirectory) {
        let reader = entry.createReader();
        asyncWaitCount++;
        let readBatch = function() {
            reader.readEntries(entries => {
                if (entries.length === 0) {
                    asyncWaitCount--;
                    if (!asyncWaitCount) upload(files);
                    return;
                }
                entries.forEach(entry => addDroppedFile(entry, files));
                readBatch();
            }, error => console.warn(error));
        };
        readBatch();
    }
    if (entry.isFile) {
        asyncWaitCount++;
        entry.file(file => {
            files.push({ file: file, path: entry.fullPath.substring(1) });
            asyncWaitCount--;
            if (!asyncWaitCount) upload(files);
        }, error => console.warn(error));
    }
}

function upload(files) {
    // The actual uploading of all dropped files
}
```

But I'm not quite happy with the use of `asyncWaitCount`. It doesn't look too robust. For instance, the value should be 1 and then 0 again in the `addFileEntries` function because the calls to `addDroppedFile` probably all take a while in the background.

So how do you handle this? When do you know that all dropped files have been read and the list is now complete?

Comment: _"which looks like it could be asynchronous (**but it's not clear**)"_ - That's never a good starting point -> [File and Directory Entries API | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API)

Comment: Well, it probably is, but the API doesn't guarantee that. The callback function might as well be called synchronously, that's still possible.